# The click event function unexpectedly called multiple times because of some unknown reasn

Tags: c#, onclick, listboxitems

Below is an click event for listbox 3. The problem   is if I don't include `listbox3.Visible=false` in the `listbox3.click` event handler it works fine. But if i include it in the code, it works fine for first selection from the `lisbox3` but for further selection, it gets called multiple times. I tried to change position of `listbox3.visible=false` statement but the it keep showing the same behaviour. if I add
    listBox3.Click -= new EventHandler(listBox3_Click); at the end of lisbox3.click(),then it works fine. But still I am nt able to understand the reason for multiple calling of the click event handler. Please help

```
private void Heading_or_project_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox3.Visible = true;
    listBox3.Click += new EventHandler(listBox3_Click);
}

public void listBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        listBox3.Visible = false;
        int i = listBox3.SelectedIndex;
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0: button1_Click(sender, e);
                break;
            case 1: new_heading_just_created = 1;
                    Heading next_heading = new Heading();
                    next_heading.per_topic_button.TabIndex = heading_wise.Count;
                    next_heading.per_topic_button.Click += new EventHandler(per_topic_button_Click);


                    flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(next_heading.head);

                    heading_wise.Add(next_heading);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem are these lines:

```
next_heading.per_topic_button.Click += new EventHandler(per_topic_button_Click);
```

And

```
listBox3.Click += new EventHandler(listBox3_Click);
```

You should call it from the form `Load` event, not here.
Because every time you call these methods (`listBox3_Click` or `Heading_or_project_Click`) you add the same handler again so it gets executed multiple times.